# nmcli stop managing a particular device

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

How can I use nmcli to temporarily stop managing a particular device?

If I list my devices I get:

```
$nmcli dev
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION         
eno1    ethernet  connected  COMPANY-LAN            
enp3s0  ethernet  connected  MY-TEST-LAN 
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

I want to be able to switch off nm control of enp3s0 temporarily, configure it by hand with `ip` or `ifconfig`, and then later, without rebooting or restarting any network services, hand control back to nm.   And I'd like to do this all through nmcli, not the GUI.

Any help / suggestions would be appreciated.

Also, if it matters, I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, nmcli version 1.2.0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In recent NetworkManager versions (1.2.0 and above):

```
nmcli dev set eth0 managed no
```

In earlier versions, the only option is to edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` to permanently unmanage a device:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:eth0
```

Comment: `nmcli dev set eth0 managed no` doesn't seems to permanently unmanage a device with NM v1.4.2.  Or, should it?

Comment: It's temporary in 1.4, will become permanent in 1.6.

Comment: @grawity, looks like it is still temporary in 1.8.4-7.fc27 version.